# MODx BabelTranslation return resources id?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, babeljs

I am strugling to get resource ID based on context with babelTranslation?

Here is my example

```
[[!getContext]]
[[BabelTranslation? &contextKey=`[[!getContext]]` &resourceId=`4`]]
```

**Snippet getContext**

```
<?php
$contextKey = $modx->context->key; 
return $contextKey
```

With this approach I alsways get nothing back, i dont know why, i hope it will return ID od translated resource from context
;

Comment: you need to echo the $contextKey not return it.

Comment: @SeanKimball return is actually correct in a snippet; snippets are executed as php functions which in fact do expect a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the `[[!getContext]]` in the `&contextKey` property there, the following snippet call should work better:

```
[[BabelTranslation? &contextKey=`other-context` &resourceId=`4`]]
```

The reason for that is the `&contextKey` property is used to determine the context of the translated resource. In your case, that was trying to load a translation *in the current context*, for a resource that is *also in the current context*. As there is no translation there, it returns nothing.

By specifying a different context that actually has a translation instead of the original resource, it can properly look it up.